# trying get all the rows in mysql table then do something

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, row

i want to make a register/login system, after i did the script there was a problem, when i want to see if the login email or the login password exist in the mysql databse i use (while resultset.next()) then check if the login email exist in the table but the problem is, it takes every row then do the if confition like it see if the first raw has the same login value then do something if it isn't it do error massage but i want it to do it after see all the rows and if all the rows don't have the login info then send the error massage

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the entire `ResultSet`, you should have the email and (hashed) password in the `where` clause:

```java
Connection con = ...;
try (PreparedStatement ps = 
     con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?") {
    ps.setString(1, loginEmail);
    ps.setString(2, hashedPassword);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            // login successful, perform some logic
        } else {
           // login not successful, perform some different logic
        }
    }
}
```